# JavaScript Recursive Node Equivalence Function Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, dom, recursion

I'm testing the following code in Chrome Dev Tools and it keeps returning true even when two nodes are not equivalent. Sample nodes are below.  Only Div1 & Div4 are equal. I'm pretty confident that I'm recursively touching all nodes, but I think I'm not setting the variable properly with the 'if', or maybe I need an else somewhere- am a little lost and have tried a bunch of things.

```
var htmlStrings = [
    '<div id="one">Some<span>node <em>contents</em> for</span>comparison</div>',
    '<div id="two">Some<span>node contents for</span>comparison</div>',
    '<div id="one">Some<span>node <strong>contents</strong> for</span>comparison</div>',
    '<div id="four">Some<span>node <em>contents</em> for</span>comparison</div>'
];

var div1 = document.createElement('div');
div1.innerHTML = htmlStrings[0];
document.body.appendChild(div1);

var div2 = document.createElement('div');
div2.innerHTML = htmlStrings[1];
document.body.appendChild(div2);

var div3 = document.createElement('div');
div3.innerHTML = htmlStrings[2];
document.body.appendChild(div3);

var div4 = document.createElement('div');
div4.innerHTML = htmlStrings[3];
document.body.appendChild(div4);


function nodeEquivalence(node1, node2) {
    var passed = false;


        if (node1.nodeType === node2.nodeType) {
            if ((node1.tagName === node2.tagName || node1.nodeValue === node2.nodeValue)) {
               passed = true;
            } 
        }

        node1 = node1.firstChild;
        node2 = node2.firstChild;
        while (node1 && node2) {
           nodeEquivalence(node1, node2);
            node1 = node1.nextSibling;
            node2 = node2.nextSibling;

        }

        return passed;

}


console.log(nodeEquivalence(div1, div2));
console.log(nodeEquivalence(div1, div4));
```

Comment: my guess is that your "tagName" is always true, thus - it will always pass. Instead of || use &&

Comment: Thanks. tried that but still have the same issue. tagName is for if it is an element, and nodeValue is for if it is a textNode, so in theory they both shouldn't be able to pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an implementation that seems to work for your test cases.  This uses recursion to test child trees.  It is specifically coded to handle elements, documents, document fragments, text nodes and comment nodes.  Support for other types of nodes could be added.

```
function nodeEquivalence(node1, node2) {
    var ch1, ch2, nType;

    // OK to have both node1 and node2 not exist, but only if both are missing
    if (!node1 || !node2) {
        return node1 === node2;
    }

    // must be same nodeType
    ntype = node1.nodeType;
    if (ntype !== node2.nodeType) {
        return false;
    }
    // if there is a tagName, must be same tagName
    if (node1.tagName && node1.tagName !== node2.tagName) {
            return false;
    }
    switch(ntype) {
        // nodes that have children
        case 1:   // element node
        case 9:   // document node
        case 11:  // document fragment node
            // check equivalence on each corresponding child
            ch1 = node1.firstChild;
            ch2 = node2.firstChild;
            while (ch1 && ch2) {
                if (!nodeEquivalence(ch1, ch2)) {
                    return false;
                }
                ch1 = ch1.nextSibling;
                ch2 = ch2.nextSibling;
            }
            return nodeEquivalence(ch1, ch2);

        // nodes whose content is nodeValue
        case 3:    // text node
        case 8:    // comment node
            return node1.nodeValue === node2.nodeValue;

        // other types of nodes
        default:
            throw new Error("unsupported type of node");
            break;
    }
}
```

And, a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/nruL6fdy/

---

There were a number of problems with your code logic:

1. You were trying to use a single local variable in recursive calls.  That doesn't work.
2. You weren't stopping the comparison as soon as a failure occured.
3. Your logic for `if (node1.tagName === node2.tagName)` would pass even if tagName didn't exist so you'd never compare the `nodeValue`.
4. Your while loop would miss the case where one node had more children than the other.

Comment: @freezycold - you're calling `nodeEquivalence(node1, node2);` and expecting it to do something, but not looking at its return value.